# Issue with SQL thinking my table name is a full table when I cast or convert it to a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I got a problem looks like with string conversion. I have tried everything under the sun. My goal is to inert the values from the loop into the table. However I can get the field value but I can not get the table name value due to sql thinks I am calling a table rather than a string. I have tried casting converting everything. Here is the code sample:

```
DECLARE @C varchar(65)
DECLARE @FieldName varchar(50)
SET @FieldName = 'ProjectID'
SELECT @C = MIN(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'Base Table'

CREATE TABLE #temp_t (
    [field] varchar(100),
    [tblname] varchar(100)
    )

WHILE @C is not null
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @qbExists int
        DECLARE @tblname varchar(100)
        SET @tblname = CONVERT(varchar(100), @C)
        SELECT @qbExists = COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @C AND COLUMN_NAME = @FieldName
        IF @qbExists = 1 AND 
           @C <> 'TimeExpenseUnionQuery' AND 
           @C <> 'TimeExpense' AND
           @C <> 'BC_BA' AND
           @C <> 'BC_BE' AND
           @C <> 'BC_EL' AND
           @C <> 'BC_TE'
          BEGIN
            EXEC('
                  SELECT ' + @FieldName + ', ' + @C + ' FROM ' + @tblName +'
                 ')
          END

        SELECT @C = MIN( TABLE_NAME ) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME > @C
END

SELECT * FROM #temp_t 

DROP TABLE #temp_t
```

The problem child lies within the SELECT ' + @FieldName + ', ' + @C + ' FROM ' + @tblName.
Now if I do not use the @C it works fine. If I try to CONVERT or CAST the @C I get an invalid column name? What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote it to make it a constant, which requires doubling up because of dynamic SQL

```
EXEC('
              SELECT ' + @FieldName + ', ''' + @C + ''' FROM ' + @tblName +'
             ')
```

Whether the use of dynamic SQL is a *good* idea or not is a different matter...

Comment: I love you, wow how could I miss that. Thank you very much buddy!

Answer (score 2):

One thing that's always a good idea when developing dynamic SQL solutions like you're doing here is printing out the statement first and making sure that it looks like you want it to.  I think the other answerers have the gist of it: it seems that you're trying to print out a string literal of your table name.  If that's the case, you'll need to surround it in quotes in the query that gets executed, which means some work when you're building the query.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to execute:

```
SELECT <fieldname>, <tablename> FROM <same tablename>
```

e.g.

```
SELECT ProjectID, myTable FROM myTable
```

Do you mean to put the tablename in quotes?